# MySQL: group rows by sum of a binary variable

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a table that I want to group by a binary variable `group_generator` that defines end of the group: if it equals `1`, then the group contains all previous rows with `group_generator = 0`

Example:

```
Numbers        group_generator    
10             0    
20             0    
30             1    
40             0    
50             1 
60             1
```

I need Numbers grouped in three groups:

```
(10, 20, 30); 
(40, 50); 
(60)
```

I tried creating a new column with sum of `group_generator` for all rows with index less than current, like this:

```
Numbers        group_generator    group
10             0                  0
20             0                  0
30             1                  0
40             0                  1
50             1                  1
60             1                  2
```

and group by the last column, but that's complicated without temporary tables.

Is there an easy way do this in MySQL?

Comment: your question si not clear .. explain better

Comment: 'all rows with index less than current' what does this mean? Do you have a column which can identify current and < current for example an auto_increment id field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have your new column, this query will give you the desired result:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Numbers) FROM table GROUP BY `group`
```

Output:

```
group_concat(numbers)
10,20,30
40,50
60
```

So the whole query could be:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Numbers),
(SELECT IFNULL(SUM(group_generator), 0) FROM table1 t2 WHERE t2.id < table1.id) AS `group`
FROM table1
GROUP BY `group`
```

Output

```
group_concat(Numbers)   group
10,20,30                0
40,50                   1
60                      2
```

You could also produce this output with a stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER //
drop PROCEDURE if EXISTS groupit
//
create procedure groupit()
begin
   declare num int;
   declare numgroup varchar(1024) default '';
   declare gnum int default 0;
   declare pid int default 1;
   declare gg int;

   DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET gg = -1;

   repeat
     select group_generator, Numbers  into gg, num from table2 where id=pid;
     if (gg >= 0) then
         set numgroup = concat(numgroup, if(numgroup='', '', ','), num);
         if (gg = 1) then
             select numgroup, gnum;
             set numgroup = '';
             set gnum = gnum + 1;
         end if;
     end if;
     set pid=pid+1;
   until gg = -1
   end repeat;
end
//
delimiter ;
```

Comment: Thanks! That solves almost whole my problem. But if instead of `table1` you had a complex expression that you don't want to repeat twice (and you can't use temporary table to store that table), how would you calculate the `SUM(group_generator)`?

Comment: Temporary tables would definitely be best, repeating the expression although messy would work, it might be possible to use a join? I'll think about it...

Comment: I guess by definition a JOIN will result in table1 being referenced more than 1, so that probably won't work either. Can you perhaps use a stored procedure? I've put an example in my answer.

Comment: That's great. I was afraid if you couldn't use temporary tables you might not be able to use stored procedures either.